# Getting alerts of another account on Stack Overflow App

Tags: discussion, android-app

I downloaded the Stack Overflow App for Android on my friends phone yesterday, he is a member of Stack Overflow too.

I logged in with my email but receives alert for my own email and his own via the App. The email he is using for the phone Google account is the same with the one he is using in Stack Overflow. I have twice received alerts of answered questions on the Stack Overflow App but they are not related to my email but his.

Is this a bug or it was built to be so?

Comment: Considering that you are using another person's phone, *and* that he/she is also part of Stack OverFlow, I'd double check what's signed in, settings, etc.